# Converting Antlr3 Syntactic Predicates to equivalent grammar in Antlr4, when number of syntactic predicates is large

Tags: antlr4, antlr3

I have Antlr3 parser rule that looks like this:

```
ruleA:
   (TOKEN_1) => TOKEN_1 ruleToken1
   | (TOKEN_2) => TOKEN_2 ruleToken2
   ....
   ....
   <many more such rules>
   | genericRuleA
;
```

Assume for a moment that the tokens and rules are appropriately defined. Also, `genericRuleA` is defined in a way that it behaves like a "catch-all" for anything that falls through the rule elements above it.

So, for example, the subrules above `genericRuleA` correspond to named functions and `ruleToken1` and `ruleToken2` capture how those named functions are called. `genericRuleA` would capture any other functions that are not named functions (e.g. a user defined function).

The net effect of this grammar is that if `ruleA` finds a `TOKEN_1`, it takes `ruleToken1` path and reports an error if the rest of the input did not satisfy `ruleToken1`

In Antlr4, I would end up with the following parser rule after taking out the syntactic predicates:

```
ruleA:
    TOKEN_1 ruleToken1
    | TOKEN_2 ruleToken2
   ....
   ....
   <many more such rules>
    | genericRuleA
;
```

This works well, except, if the rest of the `ruleToken1` fails, the parser automatically picks `genericRuleA` as the preferred path. So now, I have the side effect of being able to "overload" named functions. That may be useful in some situations, but in my situation, the requirement is to expressedly not allow this overloading i.e. named functions must conform to the specific structure laid out in `ruleToken1`, and report an error if that structure is violated. The system for which this grammar is being written does not support overloaded functions.

`genericRuleA` must cater to anything other than named functions.

**My first question: Is there a standard way to implement this conversion?**

One approach I have seen is to create a list of tokens that correspond to the named functions (TOKEN_1, TOKEN_2, etc.); construct a `@parser::member` function that returns `true` if the input token has membership in this list. So assuming a `isNamedFunction()` appropriately defined, the rule would look something like:

```
ruleA:
    TOKEN_1 ruleToken1
    | TOKEN_2 ruleToken2
    | {!isNamedFunction()}? genericRuleA
;
```

This might work when you have only a few named functions, but if you have potentially hundreds (think builtin functions in TSQL for example), that list would be pretty cumbersome to build. Not to mention that as new named functions came about, I would have to keep updating that list.

**So my follow up question is: Assuming the semantic predicate approach outlined above is the right way to do this, is there a way to programmatically assemble the list?**

One approach that appears to hold promise is to build this from `getExpectedTokens()`. Here I would re-structure the rule a little bit so all named functions fall under one rule (let's say we call it `namedRuleA`) like so:

```
ruleA:
    namedRuleA
    | genericRuleA
;

namedRuleA:
   TOKEN_1 ruleToken1
   | TOKEN_2 ruleToken2
   ....
   ....
   <many more such rules>
;
```

Then starting from ruleA's `ATNState` [`recognizer.getATN().states.get(recognizer.getState())`] I would walk down the transitions till I arrive at `namedRuleA`'s `ATNState` and then use `getATN().getExpectedTokens(<namedRuleA's ATNState>, null)` to get an `IntervalSet` that corresponds to the token types of `TOKEN_1`, `TOKEN_2`, etc.

This appears to be yielding the right set of tokens, and appears to make sense since (my understanding is that) the `ATNState` and its transitions are known and fixed at transpile time i.e. during .g4 --> .java transpiling (or whatever your target language is).

I know sometimes the transitions are dynamically determined through `closure()` calls e.g. when there are semantic predicates involves, but let's assume I can ensure no semantic predicates would be used in `namedRuleA`

I just wanted to get a sense if somebody else tried this approach and if there might be a gotcha that I'm completely missing.